# Making event pages visible

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I was wondering how can one make things like event pages or eventually membership application visible 'online'.
When I create the new event, I get a link in this style `https://.../crm/event/info/?reset=1&id=14` which leads to a 404 page upon clicking on it.
The CMS is Wordpress.

Thanks

Comment: Is the event active and public?

Comment: you may need to check your civicrm.settings.php to ensure you have things set up correctly there - just that your link above says /crm/event and that doesn't smell right to me

Comment: What would the correct setting be in that case?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that:

- you have a Wordpress page with slug `crm` in your case (the first part of your path).
- set the corresponding `WordPress Base Page` in CiviCRM : Administer -> System settings -> CMS Database Integration (or https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/uf&reset=1) :

[image]

Also, in Wordpress, it's better to keep permalinks simple with :

[image]

Last, you should ensure that clean url are properly enabled with those lines in the civicrm.settings.php (updated in recent version of CiviCRM, check file civicrm/templates/CRM/common/civicrm.settings.php.template for reference) :

```
if (!defined('CIVICRM_CLEANURL')) {
  if (function_exists('variable_get') && variable_get('clean_url', '0') != '0') {
    define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 1 );
  }
  elseif ( function_exists('config_get') && config_get('system.core', 'clean_url') != 0) {
    define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 1 );
  }
  elseif( function_exists('get_option') && get_option('permalink_structure') != '' ) {
    define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 1 );
  }
  else {
    define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 0);
  }
}
```